# Run CGI Java Program

Tags: java, apache, http, web, cgi

I want to run a java program with Apache HTTP Server. I'm struggling to show simple output in the browser.

In my cgi-bin folder I have CgiTest.java which looks like this:

```
#!"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe"
public class CgiTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String type = "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
    String output = "<html>" +
            "<p>Hi there </p>" +
            "</html>";
    System.out.println(type);
    System.out.println(output);
}
}
```

The error I get is:

```
End of script output before headers: CgiTest.java
Error: Could not find or load main class C:.Apache24.cgi-bin.CgiTest.java\r: C:/Apache24/cgi-bin/CgiTest.java
```

How to run my java program? If I have to invoke it from some script how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made it work!
For those of you who find this one day here is a way to do it:

Step 1. Java program

```
public class CgiTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
String type = "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
String output = "<html>" +
        "<p>Hi there </p>" +
        "</html>";
System.out.println(type);
System.out.println(output);
}
}
```

Step 2. Put it in cgi-bin folder

Step 3. Run javac CgiTest.java

Step 4. Install cygwin

Step 5. Create invoker.cgi in cgi-bin folder:

```
#!C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe
java -cp ./ CgiTest
```

Step 6. Configure conf/httpd.conf and Allow cgi scripts execution. Make sure you have those lines:

```
<Directory "c:/Apache24/cgi-bin">
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
Options FollowSymLinks
Require all granted
</Directory>
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
```

Step 7. Run the URL in your browser. Make sure you enter you port correctly. Mine is 180 but yours is in conf/httpd.conf

```
http://localhost:180/cgi-bin/invoker.cgi
```

This is one of the ways to do it in Windows.